# How can I find the size of a (* char) array inside of a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, size

I understand how to find the size using a string type array:

```
char * shuffleStrings(string theStrings[])
{
    int sz = 0;
    while(!theStrings[sz].empty())
    {
        sz++;
    }
    sz--;
    printf("sz is %d\n", sz);
    char * shuffled = new char[sz];
    return shuffled;
}
```

One of my questions in the above example also is, why do I have to decrement the size by 1 to find the true number of elements in the array?
So if the code looked like this:

```
char * shuffleStrings(char * theStrings[])
{
    //how can I find the size??
    //I tried this and got a weird continuous block of printing
    int i = 0;
    while(!theStrings)
    {
      theStrings++;
      i++;
    }
    printf("sz is %d\n", i);
    char * shuffled = new char[i];
    return shuffled;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your second question?

Comment: No idea what you're asking, but your function parameters are pointers, so there is no way of knowing the length of the array they might point to. You need a to pass a length separately, or use a sentinel value, which is what the first example appears to be doing.

Comment: I've answered your questions.  However I'm not sure to understand what you try with the shuffle pointer:  it'll be one char per string in the table and without place for a null terminator.  Don't you want the total size to shuffle therein the strings ?  Or do you want to store therein the indexes of the shuffled strings ?  In the last case, you should consider `sizet_t*`  instead of `char*`  (or better `vector<size_t>shuffled(i)`).

Answer (score 0):

You should not decrement the counter to get the real size, in the fist snippet. if you have two element and one empty element, the loop will end with value , which is correct.

In the second snippet, you work on a pointer to a pointr.  So the while-condition should be `*theStrings` (supposing that a NULL pointer ist the marker for the end of your table.

Note that in both cases, if the table would not hold the marker for the end of table, you'd risk to go out of bounds.  Why not work with **`vector<string>`** ?  Then you could get the size without any loop, and would not risk to go out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing here is the "termination" character in the string or `'\0'`

You can see this better when you use a char* array instead of a string.

Here is an example of a size calculator that I have made.

```
int getSize(const char* s)
{
  unsigned int i = 0;
  char x = ' ';
  while ((x = s[i++]) != '\0');
  return i - 1;
}
```

As you can see, the `char*` is terminated with a `'\0'` character to indicate the end of the string. That is the character that you are counting in your algorithm and that is why you are getting the extra character.

As to your second question, seem to want to create a new array with size of all of the strings.

To do this, you could calculate the length of each string and then add them together to create a new array.

Comment: I suspect OP to look for the size of an array of string, non a single string.  So he works with a `char**` and looks for an end of table marker (empty string in first snippet, nullptr in the second snippet).